# Invalid Taxonomy in template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, functions

I have looked through the posts here that involve this same error, without any luck.

I have a Custom Post Type (Staff) and a custom taxonomy for it. Making Staff posts and assigning terms is working fine, but I'd like to list all of the Staff in groups based on the taxonomy terms. But **the terms do not come through**.

The Template File is here: http://pastie.org/4372363

The (relevant parts of the) functions.php file is here: http://pastie.org/4372367

Any reason why I wouldn't be able to do this?

The result looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
    <h2>Array</h2>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile fourth">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <h2>Array</h2>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile fourth">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="profile">...</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

With the content of the array being another Array with one item in it, being the "Invalid Taxonomy" error (a string).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Template File, it looks like `get_terms` function is getting passed null data since the `$taxonomies` object is just an array of strings, not an array of objects. In other words, try changing:

```
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy->name );
```

to

```
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
```

Comment: Thanks!! Also, when printing the Term name, I needed to change it to the following:



`echo '<h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>';`